# Import Error while trying to import ssl in python 3.7

Tags: python, ssl, import, python-import

```
  File "c:/Users/P/admin/src/Implementations/file.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Users\P\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

This is what I am getting. I know that ssl in built-in in Python 3.x But I don't understand how to solve this,

Comment: Please share your codes!

Comment: @MohitChandel No matter what the codes are the error shows up while running the file. 
I even tried a dummy file with only the import command. And the same error shows up.

Comment: Most likely you have a ssl library in the path that python tries to load and fails (maybe diferent arch ?). I don't know a exact solution

A posible workaround can be found here:

https://bugs.python.org/issue39344

Comment: One thing you could try: open your terminal of choice (cmd line for windows) type in python and you can execute python code directly. Afterwards simply write "import ssl". For me there were no errors. Maybe use python3 if you have several versions installed

Comment: How did you install this python? From source? From installer? From some packaged thing? The process of installation might change the process of fixing. E.g. I had this exact issue with Python environment installed from script+tar and it depended on OS (my local system used for development was much different from target OS), but it got fixed with newer package. And installing from source requires correct flags. Etc

Comment: this python was installed through Anaconda3. @h4z3 My OS is Windows 10.